# How to get layout from another package in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I start a project MyFileChooser which contains package com.MyFileChooser.In my Project i have a layout abc.xml.I created another package com.FileChooser in the same project.In a class file inside the second package,i need to set abc.xml layout.But it is not possible to do so.Also i cannot acces the EditText inside abc.xml.

Comment: now its ok with com.MyFileChooser.R.But faced another problem.I cannot start activity from FileChooser package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just import

```
import com.MyFileChooser.R;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get layout by `setContentView(R.layout.abc);` now you can get all the tools of abc.xml by findviewbyid.

And no need to give any kind of Reference. Now just go to Project->Clean the Project before you Build.

Comment: did you mean the R class is only visible to the default package without import?

Comment: @KIRANKJ: check my new Answer.